# Cannot install php5-curl on Debian8

Tags: php, debian

When trying to execute 'apt-get install php5-curl" following error accurs

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.6.33+dfsg-0+deb8u1) but 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u8 is to be installed

Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install php5-dev` first.

Comment: kinda leads to the same problem as 'libpcre3-dev' is not installed and installing it triggers this error :  `libpcre3-dev : Depends: libpcre3 (= 2:8.43-1+0~20190710.6+debian8~1.gbpbfc49f) but 2:8.43-1+0~20190710.6+debian9~1.gbpbfc49f is to be installed`

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5 has been [officially unsupported for over a year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history) by now - I think you're going to struggle to resolve dependencies. Even Jessie ([the only version still shipping PHP 5 by default](https://wiki.debian.org/PHP#Available_versions), which you seem to be using) becomes [unsupported within a few months of now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Release_history).

Your best long-term plan is to plan your code's upgrade to compatibility with PHP 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Because the security repository is missing / disabled on your `sources.list.

[`php5-curl`](http://php5-curl) is available on the security repository.

You should add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
```

Then :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install php5-curl
```